# How to skip over particular cells when tabbing through an ExtJS 3 grid?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

How to skip tabbing through editable columns in ExtJs3 EditorGridPanel. i found some event override in extjs 4 but i can't find any event or method in extjs 3.

Answer (score 0):

in `beforeEdit` event of your editorGrid, check the record and field which gives you a particular cell, and `return false;` for that cell.

for ex:

`var editCondtn = function (e) {

        var grid = e.grid;

        var rowIndex = e.row;

        var columnIndex = e.column;

        var record = e.record;  // Get the Record

        var fieldName = e.field; // Get field name

        if ( record.get('id') != 1) {

            return false;

        }`

Comment: yes i already did but tab all over that return false cells thanks

Comment: grid.on('beforeEdit', function(if(skip_cell_found){return false;}){}, this);

Comment: Grid.on({"beforeedit":{fn: function(e){if(skip_cell_found){return false;}}}}); this is a working example..